# Add new columns to dataframe based on index from another dataframe in Python

Tags: python

I have two dataframe
df look like this

| Title | Description | Book ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title A | randomDesc | 14563 |
| Title B | randomDesc | 22631 |
| Title C | randomDesc | 09452 |
| Title D | randomDesc | 87243 |

my 2nd dataframe have diffrnenet information

| Book ID | Date | Rate | user ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14563 | 29/4/2021 | 8 | 90 |
| **22631** | 30/9/1990 | 6.5 | 87 |
| 09452 | 4/6/2000 | 4 | 90 |
| 87243 | 9/11/2017 | 9.5 | 30 |
| **22631** | 30/9/1990 | 9 | 30 |

I want to add title and Description data to the second data frame based on the book ID

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.merge()` might be a solution:

```
df2.merge(df1, how="left", on="Book ID")
```